# preg_match_all rtmp links and its titles

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

Hi all there I have this string:

```
All text has PHP_EOL at end of its line.
Some TITLE OF RTMP STREAM
rtmp://slww/best
Some simple text what not required to find
Another not required string line
```

Used this regex to get rtmp or http links but how can i find its titles?

```
preg_match_all("/(rtmp:+\S*)|(http:+\S*)/s", $input_lines, $output_array);
```

That rtmp or html regex works correctly but i need to capture titles of rtmp links too.

Have tried to add `^.*$^` followed by my rtmp http pattern , as `^` its start of line and `$` its end of it.
And `/s` option for search multiple lines including new line characters.

```
/^.*$^(rtmp:+\S*)|(http:+\S*)/s
```

But can not figure it out how can i find its title.
Simple what i have tried to archive is to get whole line above my regex or below my regex.

In some cases i need to grab whole line below.

Any thoughts?

Comment: And you get string by reading some file content, i guess? If text is separated with new line characters, maybe you could try with file() function. Make loop, target links with your regex and print previous and/or next var in array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually use this regex:

```
(?m)^(?<TITLE>.*)\R+(?<url>(?:rtmp|http):\S*)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/oF5pJ1/1)

Note that you are using `/s` singleline modifier that forces `.` to match newline character but you are not using dot in your pattern. You were looking for mulitline `/m` modifier that makes `^` match at the beginning of a line (I used an inline version `(?m)`).

I am not using the singleline modifier thus `.*` will match just the line before the URL line. The `\R` in my regex matches a newline sequence.

Comment: Almost there :) It could not find items with " pageurl=xxx.xx live=true swfVfy=true" regex what i have used, is `/(?<TITLE>.*)\R+(?<url>(rtmp.*|http.*|mms.*)\S)/g` but thanks You opened my mind! Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to help. I am traveling today but feel free to drop a comment if you have any more question about this.